# Capture full response in Lua Socket call

Tags: lua, luasocket, luarocks

I am trying to call a REST API through LUA. However, I am not able to capture full raw response returned by the API. Below is the code sample:

```
local http_socket = require("socket.http")
local pretty_print = require("pl.pretty")
local header = {
                 ["x-device-type"] = "M",
                 ["authorization"] = "ashdjkashd",
                 ["x-app-secret"] = "asdasda",
                 ["x-user-id"] = "asdasdasd"
                 }

r, c, h = http_socket.request {
       method = "GET",                          -- Validation API Method                           
       url = "http://google.com",   -- Validation API URL
       headers = header
}
print(r .. c)
pretty_print.dump(h)
```

I'm using lua 5.3, and luarocks version=2.4.1.
In variable c i am getting code, and in h there are a few headers. I need to capture full response returned by the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you may know, luasocket's `http.request` supports [two forms of usage](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html#request). I'm assuming you need the second form to customize the resty request for that particular API.

In this case to capture the response body you'll need to use the `sink` field with `ltn12.sink` module. For example

```
local ltn12 = require 'ltn12'

-- ...

local res = {}
r, c, h, s = http_socket.request
{
  method = "GET",               -- Validation API Method
  url = "http://google.com",    -- Validation API URL
  headers = header,
  sink = ltn12.sink.table(res)
}

res = table.concat(res)
print(res)
```

The `table.concat` is needed since the response could be comprised of multiple chunk sizes(appended to `res` as it's received).

You can also write it out to file by replacing above with `ltn12.sink.file`, eg. using `ltn12.sink.file(io.stdout)` will dump the response to standard output.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm.

Comment: I was missing the `table.concat`. Thanks!